# Visualforce form, table is not showing already existing students

Tags: visualforce

I have a form and a table of students. The form works fine, however I want the table to show the already existing students and it does not appear to be working and I have no idea why. I am new to apex and the platform in general. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
<apex:page StandardController="tudent__c">
<apex:form >

    <apex:pageBlock title="Prijava Študenta">

    <apex:actionRegion >   
    <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" id="formToRerender">                

        <apex:inputField value="{! tudent__c.Name }"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{! tudent__c.Priimek__c }"/>        
        <apex:inputField value="{! tudent__c.Naslov__c }"/>        
        <apex:inputField value="{! tudent__c.Datum_Rojstva__c }"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{! tudent__c.Letnik__c }"/>   
        <apex:inputField value="{! tudent__c.Studijski_program__c }">      
        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="formToRerender"/>       
        </apex:inputField>        
        <apex:inputField value="{! tudent__c.Samopla_niki__c }" rendered="{!tudent__c.Studijski_program__c='Izredni'}"/>  

    </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:actionRegion>   


    <apex:pageBlockButtons >

        <apex:commandButton action="{! save }" value="Save"/>

    </apex:pageBlockButtons>

</apex:pageBlock>

     <apex:pageBlock title="Študenti">

<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!tudent__c}" var="student">

    <apex:column value="{! student.Name}"/>
    <apex:column value="{! student.Priimek__c }"/>        
    <apex:column value="{! student.Naslov__c }"/>        
    <apex:column value="{! student.Datum_Rojstva__c }"/>
    <apex:column value="{! student.Letnik__c }"/>   
    <apex:column value="{! student.Studijski_program__c }"/>
    <apex:column value="{! student.Samopla_niki__c }" />

</apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>



</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Can i ask why you are deleting your question ?

Comment: Can a mod please restore the question and comments like they were? Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: if you have anything for mod please ask here http://meta.salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/ask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the `recordSetVar="students"` attribute in your `apex:page` tag like below:

```
<apex:page StandardController="tudent__c" recordSetVar="students">
```

This would create the `students` variable in your Standard List Controller that will contain a list of your `tudent__c` records.

Next, change the `value="{!tudent__c}"` in your `apex:pageBlockTable` to `value="{!students}"`, which would make your table iterate over the `tudent__c` records inside the `students` list that you defined previously.

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!students}" var="student">
```

This approach uses the Standard List Controller. For more info about Standard List Controllers, please check the following [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_sosc_associate.htm).

**UPDATE**

In order to have a separate form that will insert new records on the page that uses Standard List Controller I think that you need to use a [controller extension](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_extension.htm).

You can create your controller extensions like below:

```
public class StudentsControllerExt {

    public tudent__c NewStudent {get; set;}

    public StudentsControllerExt (ApexPages.StandardSetController controller){
        this.NewStudent = new tudent__c();
    }

    public PageReference saveNewStudent(){
        insert NewStudent;

        //this part will just reload the current page, 
        //so you'll see the new student in the table
        PageReference pageRef = new PageReference(ApexPages.currentPage().getUrl());
        pageRef.setRedirect(true);
        return pageRef;
    }
}
```

And your Visualforce page will now look like below:

```
<apex:page StandardController="tudent__c" recordSetVar="students" 
    extensions="StudentsControllerExt">
<apex:form >

    <apex:pageBlock title="Prijava Študenta">

    <apex:actionRegion >   
    <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" id="formToRerender">                

        <apex:inputField value="{! NewStudent.Name }"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{! NewStudent.Priimek__c }"/>        
        <apex:inputField value="{! NewStudent.Naslov__c }"/>        
        <apex:inputField value="{! NewStudent.Datum_Rojstva__c }"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{! NewStudent.Letnik__c }"/>   
        <apex:inputField value="{! NewStudent.Studijski_program__c }">      
        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="formToRerender"/>       
        </apex:inputField>        
        <apex:inputField value="{! NewStudent.Samopla_niki__c }" rendered="{!NewStudent.Studijski_program__c='Izredni'}"/>  

    </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:actionRegion>   


    <apex:pageBlockButtons >

        <apex:commandButton action="{! saveNewStudent }" value="Save"/>

    </apex:pageBlockButtons>

</apex:pageBlock>

     <apex:pageBlock title="Študenti">

<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!students}" var="student">

    <apex:column value="{! student.Name}"/>
    <apex:column value="{! student.Priimek__c }"/>        
    <apex:column value="{! student.Naslov__c }"/>        
    <apex:column value="{! student.Datum_Rojstva__c }"/>
    <apex:column value="{! student.Letnik__c }"/>   
    <apex:column value="{! student.Studijski_program__c }"/>
    <apex:column value="{! student.Samopla_niki__c }" />

</apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>



</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

The key changes on your VF page that I made after introducing the controller extensions are:

- The `extensions` attribute on the `apex:page` tag. This is introducing the new controller extension to your page.
- I changed your form to reference the `NewStudent` variable from the controller extension.
- And finally, the *Save* `apex:commandButton` is now calling the `saveNewStudent` method from the controller extension.
- Plus the changes to the `value` attribute of your `apex:pageBlockTable` that I already mentioned in my initial answer

Comment: @Blaž see my update, and let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: Yup, I made a mistake inside the StudentsControllerExt constructor. I updated my code, please try it now.